# Generating PNG and JPEG images of the charts on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, charts, highcharts

How to generate PNG and JPEG images of the charts on the server using JS(node.js, express.js), without even rendering the chart in a browser.

I am searching for a suitable one. But what I get is all for rendering charts in UI. I would like to save the chart image in server and would like to reuse it.

Comment: Just so we are on the same page: I looked for "node generate chart" on google and got back a good number of results. Is this what you tried and you were not satisfied with the results? And if so, why? Just so that appropriate suggestions can be made.

Comment: Could use some headless browser, render the graph there and store a screenshot or an SVG image (depends on the charting library).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I have idea of creating the chart but dont know how to save it in server path as we wish in a new name and adding the server image reference to db

Comment: @Sirko - Thanks. I got an idea with your comment. I will search with it

Comment: highcharts allows server side/command line rendering, should be quite easy to generate image

Comment: Highcharts has node export server https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server, see the section "Using as a Node.js Module".

Comment: @morganfree - I am trying. Its a good idea, Can u pls add this in answer part